# AssertionError when I use deep learning library Keras

Tags: theano, deep-learning, keras

who can give me some notice when casue this error ? I am use VGG16-net to do face recongnition.

> ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Optimization failure due to:
>
> LocalOptGroup(local_abstractconv_gemm,local_abstractconv_gradinputs_gemm,local_abstractconv_gradweight_gemm,local_conv2d_cpu,local_conv2d_gradinputs_cpu,local_conv2d_gradweight_cpu)
>
> ERROR (theano.gof.opt): node: AbstractConv2d{border_mode='valid',
>   subsample=(1, 1), filter_flip=True, imshp=(None, None, None, None),
>   kshp=(512, 512, 3, 3)}(IncSubtensor{Set;::, ::, int64:int64:,
>   int64:int64:}.0, convolution2d_26_W) ERROR (theano.gof.opt):
>
> TRACEBACK: ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\opt.py", line 1772, in
>   process_node
>       replacements = lopt.transform(node)   File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\opt.py", line 1223, in
>   transform
>       repl = opt.transform(node)   File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\nnet\opt.py", line 153,
>   in local_conv2d_cpu
>       subsample=node.op.subsample)   File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\nnet\conv.py", line 132,
>   in conv2d
>       assert image_shape[1] == filter_shape[1] AssertionError
>
> image  [None, None, None, None]  filters  [512, 512, 3, 3] Traceback
>   (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('E:/Deep Learning/vgg.py', wdir='E:/Deep Learning')
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 699, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 74, in execfile
>       exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
>
> File "E:/Deep Learning/vgg.py", line 110, in 
>       model.fit(data,label,batch_size=100,nb_epoch=10,shuffle=True,verbose=1,show_accuracy=True,validation_split=0.2)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 402, in
>   fit
>       sample_weight=sample_weight)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line
>   999, in fit
>       self._make_test_function()
>
> File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line
>   666, in _make_test_function
>       **self._function_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py", line
>   503, in function
>       return Function(inputs, outputs, updates=updates, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py", line
>   489, in **init**
>       **kwargs)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function.py",
>   line 320, in function
>       output_keys=output_keys)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\pfunc.py", line
>   479, in pfunc
>       output_keys=output_keys)
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py",
>   line 1776, in orig_function
>       output_keys=output_keys).create(
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py",
>   line 1456, in **init**
>       optimizer_profile = optimizer(fgraph)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\opt.py", line 101,
>   in **call**
>       return self.optimize(fgraph)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\opt.py", line 89, in
>   optimize
>       ret = self.apply(fgraph, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\opt.py", line 230,
>   in apply
>       sub_prof = optimizer.optimize(fgraph)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\opt.py", line 89, in
>   optimize
>       ret = self.apply(fgraph, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\opt.py", line 2196,
>   in apply
>       lopt_change = self.process_node(fgraph, node, lopt)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\opt.py", line 1777,
>   in process_node
>       lopt, node)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\opt.py", line 1673,
>   in warn_inplace
>       return NavigatorOptimizer.warn(exc, nav, repl_pairs, local_opt, node)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\opt.py", line 1659,
>   in warn
>       raise exc
>
> AssertionError

this is my code

```
def VGG_16(weights_path=None):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1),input_shape=(3,64,64)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))
    return model

    if weights_path:
        import h5py
        f = h5py.File(weights_path)
        for k in range(f.attrs['nb_layers']):
            if k >= len(model.layers):
                # we don't look at the last (fully-connected) layers in the savefile
                break
            g = f['layer_{}'.format(k)]
            weights = [g['param_{}'.format(p)] for p in range(g.attrs['nb_params'])]
            model.layers[k].set_weights(weights)
        f.close()
        print('Model loaded.')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    train_data = np.empty((5800,3,64,64),dtype='float32')
    train_label = np.empty((5800,),dtype="uint8")
    data,label = load_data(r'E:\test\face_64_64\target\train.csv',train_data,train_label)
    # Test pretrained model
    label = np_utils.to_categorical(label,58)

    model = VGG_16()
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(58, activation='softmax'))
    sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy',class_mode="categorical")
    model.fit(data,label,batch_size=100,nb_epoch=10,shuffle=True,verbose=1,show_accuracy=True,validation_split=0.2)
```

Comment: Something seems wrong with your data shape: `in conv2d assert image_shape[1] == filter_shape[1] AssertionError

image [None, None, None, None] filters [512, 512, 3, 3]`

Comment: my data shape is (3,64,64) you means it doesn't match my net?

Answer (score 2):

I’ve faced the same issue with keras/theano.  Error was solved by upgrade theano to version 0.8.2. Please check that your theano version >= 0.8.2 and try to upgrade theano to version 0.8.2 in the opposite case . For example, with using pip install:

`pip install theano==0.8.2`